# Rails, mongoid throws TypeError no implicit conversion of nil into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

1) I have installed **MongoDB** (Windows 7 64bit). Created "data/db" path and started **mongod** via cmd.

2) I have created Rails project by using RubiMine 7. I have added two lines for my **Gemfile**:

```
gem 'mongoid'
gem 'bson_ext'
```

Then I made bundle install.

3) I have run rails generator for **mongoid:config**, this added to me **mongoid.yml** file in my config folder.

4) Created scaffold with string and text attributes. This game me that kind of model:

```
class Article
    include Mongoid::Document
    field :name, type: String
    field :content, type: String
end
```

Then I launched my server. When I open my localhost:3000/articles url it gives me **TypeError no implicit conversion of nil into String** error.

I don't understand what I did wrong? I'am using last versions of ruby, rails, mongodb and mongoid.

My logs:

```
Started GET "/articles" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-28 14:30:29 +0600
Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
Rendered articles/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 16ms

ActionView::Template::Error (no implicit conversion of nil into String):
12:   </thead>
13: 
14:   <tbody>
15:     <% @articles.each do |article| %>
16:       <tr>
17:         <td><%= article.name %></td>
18:         <td><%= article.content %></td>
app/views/articles/index.html.erb:15:in
Rendered D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-     2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_source.erb (3.0ms)
Rendered D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (5.0ms)
Rendered D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_web_console.html.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within   rescues/layout (28.0ms)
```

UPDATE:

I launched rails console and started typing commands myself:

```
a = Article.new
a.title = "AAAA"
a.content = "BBBB"
a.save
```

This throwed me that kind of error:

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String
from D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/resolv.rb:190:in `open'
from D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/resolv.rb:190:in `block in  lazy_initialize'
from D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/resolv.rb:186:in `synchronize'
from D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/resolv.rb:186:in `lazy_initialize'
from D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/resolv.rb:237:in `each_address'
from D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/resolv.rb:115:in `block in each_address'
from D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/resolv.rb:114:in `each'
from D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/resolv.rb:114:in `each_address'
from D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/resolv.rb:57:in `each_address'
from D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/moped-2.0.4/lib/moped/address.rb:51:in `block in resolve'
from D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:91:in `block in timeout'
from D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:35:in `block in catch'
from D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:35:in `catch'
from D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:35:in `catch'
from D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:106:in `timeout'
from D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/moped-2.0.4/lib/moped/address.rb:50:in `resolve'
... 25 levels...
from D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_save_callbacks'
from D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
from D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mongoid-4.0.2/lib/mongoid/interceptable.rb:138:in `run_callbacks'
from D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mongoid-4.0.2/lib/mongoid/persistable/creatable.rb:116:in `prepare_insert'
from D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mongoid-4.0.2/lib/mongoid/persistable/creatable.rb:23:in `insert'
from D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mongoid-4.0.2/lib/mongoid/persistable/savable.rb:23:in `save'
from (irb):15
from D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
from D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
from D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from D:/Phantasy star/Mobi/Daniars_Project/Svadba/mongo_id_test/bin/rails:4:in `require'
from D:/Phantasy star/Mobi/Daniars_Project/Svadba/mongo_id_test/bin/rails:4:in `<top (required)>'
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

It is throwing **SAME ERROR** even by using only rails console.

Comment: I have recreated my project by using `rails new project_name --skip-active-record` command, added gems mentioned above, when I try to open page of my scaffolds it throws me **no implicit conversion of nil into String** error again. Is it BUG of mongoid or something else?

Comment: Run Rails console (`rails c`), then run your code to receive your articles and provide full backtrace of your problem. Backtrace provided above display only part of useful information i.e. position of problem in view, but not the root of problem.

Comment: Does version number of my ruby (2.1), version of my Rails (4), version of mongo (2.6) affect to mongoid??

Comment: When I run rails generator and try to do with my **Articles** like create, save or get first, It will throw that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your latest backtrace show that your don't specify host address of MongoDB. Read [this](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html#configuration) section about configuration Mongoid gem.

**Update**

Maybe your mongoid.yml has incorrect format.

**Update 2**

Run the following commands in `irb` console and provide output:

```
$  ~  irb
2.1.0 :001 > require 'resolv'
 => true
2.1.0 :002 > Resolv::Hosts::DefaultFileName
 => "/etc/hosts"
```

Seems like you doesn't have `hosts` file in windows or it has incorrect format. If you have it provide it content too.

Comment: I have generated mongoid.yml by using this command: `rails g mongoid:config`, it says identical. My **mongod** is running on **27017 port** and in **mongoid.yml** there is in `hosts:` is written `- localhost:27017`. Still `TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String` error when I try to open view of scaffold or try to use `save first create destroy` commands by rails console.

Comment: Look at **Update 2**.

Comment: It gave me `nil` value. What do I need to do. I think we are very close.

Comment: Look at [this](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/ext/win32/lib/win32/resolv.rb#L13) and [this](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/ext/win32/lib/win32/resolv.rb#L52) code. As you can see it read path to directory where should be `hosts` file from Windows Registry. Can you onen `SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters` node in registry.exe and check key `DataBasePath`. If it is doesn't exists try to create it (as string) and specify any correct directory path. Then create empty `hosts` file in this directory.

Comment: I have DataBasePath file in this directory where value is `%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc`, but there is no `hosts` file. What kind of type must `hosts` file be and what is coorect name `Hosts` or `hosts` it must have?

Comment: `hosts` is plain text file (name in lower case). [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29#File_content) described format of this file. I think you can leave it empty or insert text `127.0.0.1  localhost`

Comment: That worked, I needed to go to my `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts `, there was iCalendar file named `hosts` I have changed to file without extention and it worked. Thank you !